# Displaying data in Repeater FooterTemplate

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Update:

row is null

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
{
 Label lblDateCreated = e.Item.FindControl("lblDateCreated ") as Label;
 DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem; //row is null here <<<<
 lblDateCreated .Text = row["DateChecked"].ToString();

}
```

**END UPDATE:**

how to show data in repeater footer?...

its very silly that i have spent good amount of time figuring out but if i move the same to itemtemplate then its showing but not in footer...below is my code..

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            header...
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="rpt">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div>
                        <div class="ert">
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            footer.....
            <div id="datetime">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateChecked")%>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="save">
            <p>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/link.aspx"
                    Text="More"></asp:HyperLink></p>
            </div>
         </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

code-behind:

```
rpt.DataSource = mydatasource;
rpt.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't really see how Footer is going to work for what you want. There will only be one Footer for the whole repeater. If `DateChecked` is different for every row of your datasource, how do you determine what should be shown in the footer?

Comment: i understand but how can i have data in the footer for each row?

Comment: hmm looks like i have to use repeater inside repeater?

Comment: So you want a footer in each row?

Comment: So you want footer in each row, So finally your requirement is to show a repeater in which every row has a footer? You can do this more easily you don't need to repeater In Row template you can design an html and directly place date inside it. Please make your question specific, Do you want any specific design in the row that you think can be easily achievable using repeater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FooterTemplate is not rendered with each row , thus you cannot bind Comment of a DateItem to footer like this.

It seems that there would be only one Date Checked that you want to show in the footer.

You are looking DateChecked in DataItem that could be different for each row.

If all rows contain same DateChecked you can create a server side property to store it , you can use any rows Datechecked if all are same if not , you can store whichever date you want to show in footer (it should be any one date)
Use following block in footer to show the DateChecked
    <% = PropertyName %> 
OR 
As you already placed Label in footer, you can directly bind lblDateTime from server side using this property.

```
rpt.DataSource = mydatasource;
rpt.DataBind();

var lblDateTime = rpt.FindControl("lblDateTime") as Label;
if (lblDateTime != null)
{
   lblDateTime.Text = mydatasource.First().DateChecked;
}
```

To Bind Repeater in Footer Control

```
 void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

  // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

  // Execute the following logic for Footer only.
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {

        footerRepeater.DataSource = mydatasource;
        footerRepeater.DataBind();
  }
 }
```

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        header...
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="rpt">
            <div class="inner">
                <div>
                    <div class="ert">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        footer.....
       <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <div>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateChecked")%>'></asp:Label>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
     </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

CS

To Bind Repeater in Footer Control

```
 void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

  // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

  // Execute the following logic for Footer only.
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {

        footerRepeater.DataSource = mydatasource;
        footerRepeater.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: so for every row i will have different DateChecked... so in this scenario what to use GridView? or any other control that iterates?

Comment: In that case you have to place another repeater inside footer template and bind this repeater in RowDataBound event, I've updated my answer

Comment: i havent tried but just wondering how that parent and child row will be sync?

Comment: Is there any kind relation like parent and child? I suppose you want to show all the dates in footer, am I correct?

Comment: there is no relation and data is coming from one datasource

Comment: yes answer to your question, want to show dates in every footer in row

Comment: So you want footer in each row, So finally your requirement is to show a repeater in which every row has a footer? You can do this more easily you don't need to repeater In Row template you can design an html and directly place date inside it.

Answer (score 3):

The footer is only rendered once for the entire dataset, while the item templates is rendered for every item in the collection.

*EDIT*

Repeater renders like so:

Header

ItemTemplate

ItemTemplate

... (one item template for each item in the datasource)

ItemTemplate

ItemTemplate

Footer

If you want something to appear in the footer of each row, you just need to add that markup to your `ItemTemplate`

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="rpt">
            <div class="inner">
                <div>
                    <div class="ert">
                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="footer">
            footer.....
            <div id="datetime">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateChecked")%>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

*END EDIT*

You could probably override the ItemDataBound or DataBound event, and access your footer there if you need to set a value.

Modified from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx)

```
   void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

      // Execute the following logic for Footer only.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer) {

            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDateTime")).Text= /* your value */;
      }
   }
```

Comment: DataBound is the proper event (at on ItemDataBound the footer is not built)

Answer (score 1):

The *FooterTemplate* is not bound to data items. When the repeater is built, the controls inside the *FooterTemplate* don't bind so the data bound expressions are not evaluated.

What you can do is to use the FindControl method.

```
rpt.DataSource = mydatasource;
rpt.DataBind();

var lblDateTime = rpt.FindControl("lblDateTime") as Label;
if (lblDateTime != null)
{
   lblDateTime.Text = mydatasource.First().DateChecked;
}
```

You see, I'm calling the First() method to obtain a single item, this is because there is only one rendered  Footer and this why I'm saying that this template is not for the items.

Comment: You still didn't get the idea. The FooterTemplate is not instantiated when the control loops through the items, is created after the loop is ended.

Comment: i understand but how can i have data in the footer for each row?